# How to Hot-Reload in ReactJS Docker

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, docker

This might sound simple, but I have this problem.

I have two `docker` containers running. One is for my `front-end` and other is for my `backend` services.

these are the `Dockerfile`s for both services.

**front-end** `Dockerfile` :

```
# Use an official node runtime as a parent image
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY package.json /app

RUN npm install --silent

# Add rest of the client code
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm start
```

**backend** `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM python:3.7.7

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY server.py /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8083

# CMD ["python3", "-m",  "http.server", "8080"]
CMD ["python3", "./server.py"]
```

I am building images with the `docker-compose.yaml` as below:

```
version: "3.2"

services:

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    depends_on: 
      - backend

  backend: 
    build: ./backends/banuka
    ports: 
      - 8080:8083
```

**How can I make this two services `Update` whenever there is a change to front-end or back-end**?

I found this repo, which is a booilerplate for `reactjs`, `python-flask` and `posgresel`, which says it has enabled `Hot reload` for both `reactjs` frontend and `python-flask` backend. But I couldn't find anything related to that. Can someone help me?

[repo link](https://github.com/tomahim/react-flask-postgres-boilerplate-with-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

What I want is: **after every code change the container should b e up-to-date automatically !**

Comment: You need to add CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLIN=true in your compose env

Comment: @AtinSingh to all the services?

Comment: for your frontend. But I guess you need it for backend too if you are using nodemon

Comment: I don't use `nodemon`. It is a simple python server. How can I do this to backend?

Comment: Sorry no idea about Python. I only worked on node,js

Comment: @AtinSingh it doesn't work, I don't know why. The app is running but it doesn't update when a change is happen. I added `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLIN=true` for the frontend, but doesn't work (update automatically)

Comment: Okay I had same problem a year ago. I'll take a quick check how I did it.

Comment: This worked for me https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-create-react-app-in-docker-container/#Hot-Reloading-not-working

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this in your docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.2"

services:

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./frontend:/app
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    depends_on: 
      - backend

  backend: 
    build: ./backends/banuka
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    volumes:
      - ./backends/banuka:/app    
    ports: 
      - 8080:8083
```

Basically you need that chokidar environment to enable hot reloading and you need volume bindings to make your code on your machine communicate with code in container. See if this works.

Comment: Sso you have put `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"` in the `backend`. I guess this is working for `reactjs`/front-end changes as well?

Comment: @user13456401 yes, it should. Try it.

Comment: I will get back to you once this is tested. Are you on any other social media I can reach out to you?

Comment: @user13456401 I am quite active on SO you can reach me here. I am also on reddit. u/auctus10.

Comment: Thank you. I will reach out to you if there is a problem in here

Comment: Now I am getting this error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/aframe-extras/src/controls/keyboard-controls.js'`

Comment: Okay remove this `- /app/node_modules` from frontend service

Comment: I removed all the node_modules and did a fresh `npm install` and worked, Didn't have to remove the `/app/node_modules`. Now can you tell me how you have mounted these volumes? And why you have mounted `node_modules` as well?

Comment: @user13456401 Glad it worked. I think you may not need to mount node_modules. I did it because yarn screws up version dependency. You can try removing it. Make sure to keeep `.dockerignore` and keep node modules in it so that your container forms well. As for the other mounted volumes. I have basically connected your source code on machine to container. So that the code inside container can detect changes. It is usually isolated so reloading doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am deploying this application with `gitlab-runner`. Now the problem is, when I make a change to the repo and push, pipeline fails saying `warning: failed to remove frontend/node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/f3c7e47b8c912de1f86f219bc5bb266630277bc5.json.gz: Permission denied`

Comment: @user13456401 seems like a permission issue. Ask someone with a higher role than you to see to it.

Comment: I have the higher roles. I guess this issue is because now since there is a docker volume and everytime a new pipeline runs, it tries to remove the older repo and get a fresh copy of the repo with latest changes, it is having problems because of that volume?

Comment: I am not quite sure what the error is but you don't need hot reloading at deployment right? Your frontend code is static build and even your server should not have reloading (restart, yes). So make separate dockerfiles for deployment and development.

Comment: @AtinSingh I tried your guide but still not working. I change something on react app still not reload anything

Comment: works like charm

Comment: Note that, as of version `5.x.x` of `react-scripts`, you will have to replace the variable `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING` with `WATCHPACK_POLLING` (it's a drop-in replacement). See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12397

Answer (score 4):

If you are mapping your react container's port to a different port:

```
    ports:
      - "30000:3000"
```

you may need to tell the WebSocketClient to look at the correct port:

```
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true # create-ui-app <= 5.x
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true # create-ui-app >= 5.x
      - FAST_REFRESH=false
      - WDS_SOCKET_PORT=30000 # The mapped port on your host machine
```

See related issue:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11779

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Adding just the last environment variable worked for me: `WDS_SOCKET_PORT=<host port>`. Setup: docker-compose: `FROM node:16-alpine` (node 16.20.0).

Comment: Complementing my last comment: `react-scripts 5.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, following somethingRandom's reply to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61577792/15736486) resolved the issue.

While using `react-scripts 5.0.1`, 
`CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING` didn't function as expected, 
but setting `WATCHPACK_POLLING = True` did the trick.