# Hot-Reload in React using Docker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker

I have 2 docker containers running, one for an API and one for the front-end (build with React) of the application. I would like the front-end container to be updated whenever I make a change. The API container does not have to be updated on change.

doker-compose.yml:

```js
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.api
    image: controle-app-api

  client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.client
    image: controle-app-client
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
```

Dockerfile.client:

```js
# Build step #1: build the React front end
FROM node:16-alpine as build-step

# Specify where our app will live in the container
WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# Copy the React App to the container
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./public ./public

# Prepare the container for building React
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g
# We want the production version
RUN npm run build

# Prepare nginx
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build-step /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY deployment/nginx.default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

I tried applying the answer given at [How to Hot-Reload in ReactJS Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61576659/how-to-hot-reload-in-reactjs-docker), but this did not help. Whenever I edit something in a .JS file, it is not updated on reload of the application.

Comment: A couple of things I noticed: You use Nginx to serve your frontend files. I haven't seen Nginx used with hot reload. Also, you map your current directory to /app in the Nginx container, but Nginx usually serves files from /usr/share/nginx/html (that's also where you copy your files during build), so I don't think your mapping has any effect.

Comment: You should be able to use an ordinary non-Docker host development environment, targeting the `api` container running in Docker (you may need to add `ports:` to it to be able to proxy to it).