# Hot-Reload in React with Docker-compose

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, create-react-app

I've tried to implement the solution given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61576659/how-to-hot-reload-in-reactjs-docker) but it doesn't work. Can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.

File structure looks like this:

```
backend/
  - Dockerfile
frontend/
  - node_modules/
  - src/
  - Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
```

frontend/Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.13.2

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm ci
EXPOSE 3000
COPY . ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  backend:
    build: backend/.
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - frontend
  frontend:
    build: frontend/.
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    volumes:
      - './frontend:/app'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

I'm almost certain it's my volumes that are defined wrong, just can't seem to figure out the exact details.

EDIT:
It would appear that this is an issue with the latest version of create-react-app. Ref github issues: [#11879](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11879) and [#11897](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11897)

Comment: I probably wouldn't recommend an isolation system based on immutable images for day-to-day development.  Can you use plain Node instead, without Docker?  You can run `docker-compose up -d backend` to start only the backend service and set something like your Webpack proxy configuration to point at its published `ports:`.

Comment: Yeah I know it would more practical, but we are a team of seven students with varying technical knowledge working on a project, so having a single "start"/"stop" command that makes everything just *work* together would make it a lot easier for the less-technical members to be able to contribute.