# docker-compose: how to automatically propagate changes (both frontend and backend)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In Docker Compose, we have two services (a backend in Flask and a frontend in React) running at the same time in different directories. What are best practices for automatically updating the frontend service or backend service when ha change to the respective code is made?

In our case, we have:

```
frontend/
  index.html
  docker-compose.yml
  Dockerfile
  src
    App.js
    index.js
    ..
```

And our backend is:

```
backend/
  app.py
  Dockerfile
  docker-compose.yml
```

This is our `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  frontend:
    image: node:alpine
    build:
      context: ../frontend
      dockerfile: ../frontend/Dockerfile
    command: npm start
    depends_on:
      - database # dont start until the database is up
      - app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
    - .:/frontend
  app:
    image: python:3.9
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: app.py
    depends_on:
      - database # dont start until the database is up
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
    - PGPASSWORD=magical_password
    - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=magical_password
    - POSTGRESQL_HOST=backend-database-1
    - POSTGRESQL_USER_NAME=unicorn_user
    - LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT=True
    - FLASK_ENV=development
    - REPLICATE_API_TOKEN
    volumes:
    - .:/app
  database:
    image: "postgres" # use latest official postgres version
    env_file:
      - database.env # configure postgres
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even if container shuts down
      - ./schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
volumes:
  database-data: # named volumes can be managed easier using docker-compose
```

Typically, we reload the app (on change) almost instantly from a volume in the volume's section. This approach correctly changes the backend service when the backend code is changed, but not the frontend service. Also, we have 2 `docker-compose` files, one in frontend, one in backend, which we hope to somehow learn how to consolidate.

Edit: These are the logs that work for the backend (app_1 is the backend) but do not work for the frontend:

```
app_1       |  * Detected change in '/app/app.py', reloading
app_1       | environ({'PATH': '/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin', 'HOSTNAME': '***', 'PGPASSWORD': '***', 'POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD': 'magical_password', 'POSTGRESQL_HOST': 'backend-database-1', 'POSTGRESQL_USER_NAME': '***', 'LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT': 'True', 'FLASK_ENV': 'development', 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8', 'GPG_KEY': '***', 'PYTHON_VERSION': '3.9.13', 'PYTHON_PIP_VERSION': '22.0.4', 'PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION': '58.1.0', 'PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL': 'https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/6ce3639da143c5d79b44f94b04080abf2531fd6e/public/get-pip.py', 'PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256': '***', 'HOST': '0.0.0.0', 'PORT': '8080', 'HOME': '/root', 'KMP_INIT_AT_FORK': 'FALSE', 'KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK': 'True', 'WERKZEUG_SERVER_FD': '3', 'WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN': 'true'})
app_1       |  * Restarting with stat
app_1       |  * Tip: There are .env or .flaskenv files present. Do "pip install python-dotenv" to use them.
app_1       |  * Debugger is active!
app_1       |  * Debugger PIN: 203-417-897
```

Edit 2: We followed the link suggested in the comments. We attempted setting both `WATCHPACK_POLLING` and `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING` to `“true”` but no luck. And we refactored our docker-compose file to be outside the directories like so:

```
docker-compose.yml
frontend/
  index.html
  Dockerfile
  src
    App.js
    index.js
    ..
backend/
  app.py
  Dockerfile
```

Here is the new docker-compose
version: '3.8'

```
services:
  frontend:
    image: node:alpine
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      cache_from:
        - node:alpine
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: npm start
    depends_on:
      - database # dont start until the database is up
      - app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING="true"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./frontend:/app
  app:
    image: python:3.9
    build:
      context: ./backend
      cache_from:
        - python:3.9
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: backend/app.py
    depends_on:
      - database # dont start until the database is up
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
    - PGPASSWORD=magical_password
    - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=magical_password
    - POSTGRESQL_HOST=backend-database-1
    - POSTGRESQL_USER_NAME=unicorn_user
    - LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT=True
    - FLASK_ENV=development
    - REPLICATE_API_TOKEN
    volumes:
      - .:/app
  database:
    image: "postgres" # use latest official postgres version
    env_file:
      - backend/database.env # configure postgres
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even if container shuts down
      - ./schema.sql:/backend/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
volumes:
  database-data: # named volumes can be managed easier using docker-compose
  app:
```

And here are our Dockerfile for frontend

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN mkdir -p /frontend
WORKDIR /frontend
# We copy just the package.json first to leverage Docker cache
COPY package.json /frontend
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps
COPY . /frontend
# Bind to all network interfaces so that it can be mapped to the host OS
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3000
EXPOSE ${PORT}
CMD ["npm", "start"]
and backend
FROM python:3.9
# We copy just the requirements.txt first to leverage Docker cache
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
# Bind to all network interfaces so that it can be mapped to the host OS
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=8080
EXPOSE ${PORT}
# This runs the app in the container
CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

Still backend hot reloads and every time we make a change the change is detected and picked up and reflected in docker-compose immediately. But frontend requires a restart with this command `docker-compose down --volumes && docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose` up the output we get from docker-compose is no logs. It’s like docker-compose can’t see the changes.

Edit 3: Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this. How did you create them? do you have a CICD pipeline, where are your docker images stored and pulled from?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle , I'm adding more information now. One sec...

Comment: @ChrisDoyle , is that additional information helpful?

Comment: If the backend reloads fine, then this sounds like an issue of 'react not auto-reloading inside docker'.  In which case have you tried something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61577792/2052575.  [Further researching `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/) shows: **When set to `true`, the watcher runs in polling mode, as necessary inside a VM. Use this option if `npm start` isn't detecting changes.**

Comment: @v25 we tried both `WATCHPACK_POLLING` and `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING` and neither worked. We added details to the post above.